# Winforms App with basic MVP pattern using EF and SQL back-end

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, mvp

I'm writing an application and after reading and following many examples I have implemented a basic MVP pattern. On simple maintenance screens it works really well; however on more complex screens the pattern is not so good.

Here is a short code block with the interface and the first method to fetch some data via LINQ. The presenters are all separate to the model, each model POCO was generated via EF-codefirst.

```
public interface ILocnMastView
    {
        int LocnMastID { get; set; }
        Int16 LocnSubTypeID { get; set; }

        event EventHandler<EventArgs> FetchLocnMasts;

        //Event to fire a 'fetch' of a row of data
        event EventHandler<EventArgs> RefreshLocnMast;
    }
    public interface ILocnMastData : ILocnMastView
    {
        //Event to fire a record INSERT
        event EventHandler<EventArgs> InsertLocnMast;

        //Event to fire a record UPDATE
        event EventHandler<EventArgs> UpdateLocnMast;
    }

    public class PresenterLocnMast
    {
        #region Member Variables
        private ILocnMastView _viewfetch;                 //The view (form) instance that this presenter interface will use
        private ILocnMastData _viewdata;                  //The view (form) instance that this inherited interface will use
        private LOCNMast _obj = new LOCNMast();             //A single row of data to be returned out of this class
        private List<LOCNMast> _data = null;              //List of supplycodes to be returned out of this class
        private List<LocnMastObject> _dataobject;    //List of contacts joined to persontype table in a specialised class object
        private string _message = string.Empty;
        #endregion Member Variables

        #region Member Properties

        public string Message
        {
            get { return _message; }
            set { _message = value; }
        }
        public LOCNMast Locnmast
        {
            get { return _obj; }
            set { _obj = value; }
        }
        public List<LOCNMast> LocnMasts
        {
            get { return _data; }
            set { _data = value; }
        }
        public List<LocnMastObject> LocnMastObjects
        {
            get { return _dataobject; }
            set { _dataobject = value; }
        }
        #endregion Member Properties

        #region Member Objects
        public class LocnMastObject
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string combinedtext { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string LocationType { get; set; }
            public string Warehouse { get; set; }
            public string Category { get; set; }
            public DateTime LastEditedDate { get; set; }
            public string LastEditedBy { get; set; }
            public Boolean Active { get; set; }
        }
        #endregion Member Objects

        #region Init
        public PresenterLocnMast(ILocnMastView viewfetch, ILocnMastData viewdata)
        {
            this._viewfetch = viewfetch;
            this._viewdata = viewdata;
            this.Initialise();
        }

        private void Initialise()
        {
            if (_viewdata != null)
            {
                this._viewdata.UpdateLocnMast += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(UpdateLocnMast);
                this._viewdata.InsertLocnMast += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(InsertLocnMast);
            }
            this._viewfetch.FetchLocnMasts += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(FetchLocnMasts);
            this._viewfetch.RefreshLocnMast += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(RefreshLocnMast);
        }
        #endregion Init

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Routine:    FetchLocnMasts
        /// Purpose:    Event to Fetch all details from the database by locnsubtype
        /// Author:     Frustrated Winforms Developer
        /// Date:       13/11/2015
        /// </summary>
        private void FetchLocnMasts(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new DevDBContext())

                    var queryforobject = from l in db.LOCNMasts.AsNoTracking()
                                         join t in db.LocnTypes.AsNoTracking() on l.LocationTypeID equals t.ID
                                         join w in db.WHMasts.AsNoTracking() on l.WarehouseID equals w.ID
                                         join c in db.LocnCategoryTypes.AsNoTracking() on l.LocationCategoryTypeID.Value equals c.ID into pp
                                         from LocationCategoryTypeID in pp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                         orderby l.Name

                                         //Put the query results into the bespoke object
                                         select new LocnMastObject { ID = l.ID, 
                                                                     Name = l.Name, 
                                                                     Description = l.Description, 
                                                                     combinedtext = l.Name + " - " + l.Description,
                                                                     LocationType = t.Description,
                                                                     Warehouse = w.Description,
                                                                     Category = LocationCategoryTypeID.Name,
                                                                     LastEditedBy = l.LastEditedBy, 
                                                                     LastEditedDate = l.LastEditedDate, 
                                                                     Active = l.Active };
                    if (queryforobject.Count() > 0)
                        _dataobject = queryforobject.ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //HandleError
            }
        }
```

So, all okay.
On the form, I have to implement the interface, set private member vars and properties for the key fields, create an instance of the presenter class and create events to match those defined in the interface.

So, on a form that has to pull data from say 6 presenter classes, the code is top heavy with multi implementations, mutli ID properties for each table and so on. On complex forms the approach offers no major advantages over a traditional OOP approach.

Any ideas as to how I can get round this? Another class with my related tables that inherits from the necessary presenters?

Code on form (note the three interface implementations):

```
public partial class frmConfigLocation : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm, IWHMastView, ILocnCategoryTypeView, ILocnMastData
#region Member Variables
private Int16 _locationcategorytypeid = -1;
        private Int16 _whmastid = -1;
        private int _locnmastid = -1;
        private Int16 _locnsubtypeid = -1;
        private PresenterWHMast _presenterwhmast;
        private PresenterLocnCategoryType _presenterlocncategorytype;
        private PresenterLocnMast _presenterlocnmast;
        #endregion Member Variables

        #region Member Events
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> FetchLocnCategoryTypes;
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> RefreshLocnCategoryType;    

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> FetchWHMasts;     
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> RefreshWHMast;

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> FetchLocnMasts;
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> RefreshLocnMast;
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> UpdateLocnMast;
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> InsertLocnMast;
        #endregion Member Events

public Int16 LocnCategoryTypeID
        {
            get { return _locationcategorytypeid; }
            set { _locationcategorytypeid = LocnCategoryTypeID; }
        }
        public Int16 WHMastID
        {
            get { return _whmastid; }
            set { _whmastid = WHMastID; }
        }
        public int LocnMastID
        {
            get { return _locnmastid; }
            set { _locnmastid = LocnMastID; }
        }
        #endregion Member Properties

        #region FormMethods
        public frmConfigLocation()
        {
            this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(frmLocation_FormClosed);
            InitializeComponent();
            _presenterlocnmast = new PresenterLocnMast(this, this);
            _presenterlocncategorytype = new PresenterLocnCategoryType(this, null);
            _presenterwhmast = new PresenterWHMast(this, null);
        }
```

So, after all that, the routine to fill a radGrid is simple enough

```
private void FetchData([Optional] Boolean postsave)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                if (FetchLocnMasts != null)
                {
                    FetchLocnMasts(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    radGridViewLocnAll.DataSource = _presenterlocnmast.LocnMastObjects;

                    //Hide the ID column of the radgrid
                    GlobalControlMethods.radGridViewColumnVisible(radGridViewLocnAll, 0, false);
                    radGridViewLocnAll.CurrentRow = null;

                }
```

As you can see a lot of code is required to set everything up although the fetching of data is straightforward. I must be missing something to make the code behind the form a lot less, which is the point surely?

Sorry for the long post and all feedback welcomed!

Comment: I think you may need to boil this down to a **much** smaller code sample and problem statement.  For me, this is wayyyyy to much to look at and I'll just move on. Others may vote to close as too broad. Another possible close reason: "Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: I know it's long but felt I couldn't illustrate the issue without providing a full example